# How do I call custom methods in a Wcf Data Service from a Silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, wcf-data-services, odata, azure-table-storage

I have the following Wcf Data Service:

```
public class WcfDataService : DataService<WcfDataServiceContext>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
    }

    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<Person> GetPeopleByName(string name)
    {
        WcfDataServiceContext context = this.CurrentDataSource;

        var match = from p in context.People
                    where p.FirstName == name
                    select p;

        return match;
    }
```

I can access the custom method from the browser like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/DataService/WcfDataService.svc/GetPeopleByName?name='Daniel'
```

How can I call that method and get that list of Person from a Silverlight application?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, Silverlight 5, .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: Sorry to join the party late. Is there a reason you added this service op, or is it just exemplary? The awesome part about OData is that it handles all of the standard queries (which the example above is) out of the box. In this case, the following URL would return you the same thing: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/DataService/WcfDataService.svc/People?$filter=FirstName eq 'Daniel'`. Correspondingly, the client-side LINQ components make it easy for you to write that query: `context.People.Where(p => p.FirstName == "Daniel")`. I can elaborate if necessary.

Comment: Hello Mark. Thank you for your reply. I implemented the query in the client. I'm currently having issues using string.Contains within Silverlight. Original question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057260/error-in-wcf-data-service-when-using-string-contains-within-linq-statement-from
How do you implement string.Contains to generate substringof('text',DisplayName) eq true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember whe using Silverlight you cannot connect to a different server than the one the Silverlight app came from so you would just use a relative Uri. If you would like to use WCF Data Services client you can take a look here: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/208481.aspx - there is a code snippet that shows it. However AFAIK WCF Data Services client does not support Service Operation so you may need to use XmlReader to be able to query and parse the response of the GetPeopleByName function.

Comment: Hi Pawel, I added a service reference to my Silverlight application. I didn't know that wcf data services client does not support custom methods. So that means that all the filtering that I have to do to "context.People" would have to be done on the client, just like the example you sent me. I'll try this tomorrow. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hi Pawel, I tried using my wcf data service, and I'm successfully querying my Entities. I added a partial class of my Wcf Data Service reference in Silverlight and I'm creating my custom methods there. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did it before I can share.Service Reference your domain:8080/DataService/WcfDataService.svc then
For Person object use **[DataContract]** attribute for properties of  Peson use **[global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]**  By this way you say Serialize and create proxies to Bus side. Notice this attributes because it really works!

```
//Here is the interface attributes are important

 namespace AHBSBus.Web.Services
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IChatService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool LogIn(Guid userID,Guid roomID);

    [OperationContract]
    bool LogOut(Guid userID,Guid roomID);

    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<VW_CHATUSERDETAIL> GetLatestMessages(Guid userID,Guid roomID,Guid lastSyncMessageID);

    [OperationContract]
    bool SendMessage(Guid fromID, Guid roomID, Guid toID, string message);

    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<ChatUser> GetLoggedInUsers(Guid roomID);

    [OperationContract]
    bool IsLogin(Guid roomID,Guid userID);
}
}


//Implementation of service 

   [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
  public partial class ChatService:IChatService
  {
    //Here goes 
  }
```